# Django ORM join on single table

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-orm

I have SQL/ORM related question, there is one model NewsArticle with ~500k objects - querying on it causes some performance issues.
Model more or less looks like this:

```
Class NewsArticle(models.Model):
    date_published = models.DateTimeField()
    duplicates_group_id = models.UUIDField(blank=False, null=True)
    duplicates = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey('NewsTopic', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    online = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
```

What I need is to group by duplicates_group_id and iterate only on articles with lowest id from every matching duplcates_group.
In SQL following query is quite fast(uses proper db indexes):

```
SELECT 
    l.`*` # fields dont matter now
FROM `summarizer_newsarticle` l
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT MIN(id) AS first_article_id
         FROM `summarizer_newsarticle`
         WHERE date_published >= '2019-12-02 00:00:00'
         GROUP BY duplicates_group_id) r 
    ON l.id = r.first_article_id
WHERE
    l.`online` = 1 AND l.`topic_id` = 5
```

In View for displaying those articles in get_queryset method I struggle to prepare proper query.
Also raw SQL didnt solve the issue because **get_queryset** expects returning queryset object. 
Without sufficient SQL queries performance is really bad
Do you maybe have an idea if its even possible to reproduce such query or to do it different way?
Thank you

Comment: Not sure I follow why you can't use `raw` here... it ends up returning a `RawQuerySet` which you can treat like any other...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The reason RawQuerySet is not sufficient is later on I need to operate on queryset returned from get_queryset() method. For example for django filters usage. They uses queryset from view.

Comment: Okay... unless I'm missing something (possibly relating to what django-filters expects), why not just override the `get_queryset()` method to return the `RawQuerySet` from your raw query?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason - apparently RawQuerySet is incompatible with django filters as stated in https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/271

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: It's 2.1.5 right now

Comment: I've also tried to get ids using raw query and filter using `NewsArticle.objects.filter(id__in=article_ids)`, but it is killing web server(100% CPU, memory also exceeded) and eventually times out

Comment: I don't have something handy (nor time to set something up) but I think you might be able to get away with using window functions in Django 2 onwards... Off the top of my head just typing this out - that'll probably be something like: `NewsArticle.objects.filter(online=1, tpoic_id=5).annotate(_n=Window(expression=RowNumber(), partition_by=F('duplicates_group_id'), order_by=F('id'))).filter(_n=1)`... (obviously import the needful...)

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but received `Window is disallowed in the filter clause.`

Comment: Ahhh... seems you're right :( https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30104 - sorry 'bout that... that's what I get for suggesting something off the top of my head - sorry to send you on a potential goose chase... maybe ORM'ing up your sql will do it... (but then sounds like you might have had a go at that building ids...)

Comment: No problem, that's actually my question: how to use my SQL in Django so it will be recognized as QuerySet and django-filters will be able to use it